# Ignore validation rules if input value is empty ("")

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form to create a conference and I have some validation rules like below. For example the city is not required but should be a string. The issue is that when the user click in the "Store" button without fill the non required fields it appears the validation errors like:

> The city must be a string.

Do you know how to solve that issue? If the value of the form field is "" ignore the rules?

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'categories' => 'array|between:1,3',
            'city' => 'string',
            'zip_code' => 'string',
        ]);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Add `nullable` rules `'city' => 'nullable|string'`

Comment: Try `nullable`. I think the input is not an empty string but `null`

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears an error "Data missing" it seems that the error is related to "Carbon/Carbon.php" with "            'date' => 'nullable|date_format:"d F Y - H:i"',
".

Comment: The question you posted has nothing to do with dates. It's a different issue then

Comment: Thanks, it was other issue, it works with nullable.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

you can use nullable if  anyone field is non requied field.below you can see  the code...

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'categories' => 'nullable|array|between:1,3',
            'city' => 'nullable|string',
            'zip_code' => 'nullable|string',
        ]);
        ...
    }
```